# Purpose of Call<T> type with Retrofit POST

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

New to http requests and java and retrofit so this is probably a basic question but...

I've managed to setup successful http calls to a web service, but was a little confused on one part, mostly based on what I've seen from tutorials/examples.

I've seen a number of examples with something like this:

```
@POST("/api")
Call<Foo> savePost(@Body Foo foo);
```

My understanding is that the argument 'foo' will be converted to json by the chosen converter and passed as the body of the http request. What I don't understand is why the response body type for Call is also Foo? Is the assumption here that the response will also be deserialized into a Foo object? Is it common practice to have a response that matches the body you're sending? I get using that for something like a GET, but don't really follow why you would expect a response like that for a POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me explain what is call in **Retrofit**

It is a Retrofit Interface, can be called synchronously through execute or asynchronously through enqueue. In either case the it can be canceled at any time with cancel.

> void enqueue(Callback callback);

```
Asynchronously send the request and notify
```

> Response execute() throws IOException;

```
Synchronously send the request and return its response.
```

In the above example, the Response you will get from the savePost is also Foo.It will deserialise to Foo object.

Its depends on usecase, wheather you have to get the Foo object or not, If you dont want that you can use **ResponseBody** instead of Foo

Comment: Ok, so does the Foo response come from retrofit? Or does it come from the web service I'm sending the request to? I guess I'm still a little confused on what the use case would be for wanting a response that contains data you already sent and presumably have access to.

Comment: @DrowningFish... Basically u will get json response from webservice. With the help of the JSON parser like GSON or Jackson Convertor , the json deserialised into Foo object.The above one is the rare use case. May be server will generate any unique reference id for the object .